# Android getText a text from EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm adding a text in EditBox with setText code.After I'm changing this text into EditText and I want to get in a String value this text with getText.But this returning null.

My code:

```
EditText kullanilan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_kullanilacakSayi);
 gunSayi = Double.toString(izinGun); // gunSayi is string value
  kullanilan.setText(gunSayi);
       String songunSayi=kullanilan.getText().toString();
```

Comment: `EditText#getText().toString()` will not return `null`. Do you mean it's returning an empty `String`? Or that it's throwing a `NullPointerException`? Or something else?

Comment: When you setText to EditText  and when you are getText() from editText?

Comment: Yes it's returning an empty value.First,I'm changing  text with setText in EditText.After I'm changing different text in editText with manuel and I want to get text in EditText

Comment: I am doing a calculation and I get the returned value.I am writing this value into a EDITTEXT.Then I change this value with my own hand.I want to get the most recent version in EdiText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
 kullanilan.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           songunSayi=kullanilan.getText().toString();
       }
   });
    }
```